# Microsoft InkCanvas in web applications

Tags: asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller, inkcanvas

I am working on a proof of concept where I intend to leverage InkCanvas to capture strokes of stylus by the user and covert it into  text.

However, the same is required to work in a web application.

I have seen very few posts on Inkcanvas. Therefore need clarification on following idea:-

1. Capture user strokes on a canvas element on the web page.
2. Make an Ajax call to server with the captured strokes.
3. Process these strokes at server end using Inkcanvas.
4. Return the identified text.
5. Update the form field in the web page, thereby enabling a stylus use in my web application.

Request if the gurus on the subject may review and give feedback.